# How can I get the shell-script-mode in Emacs to intepret #PBS -S /bin/bash to be a bash shell code?

Tags: linux, bash, emacs, shell-script, portable-batch-system

I am using Emacs on a LINUX system that uses Portable Batch System (PBS) for controlling the use of resources. The PBS scripts require "#PBS -S /bin/..." as the first line in the script to declare the shell of the script to PBS. When I load the script into Emacs, there is no #!/bin/... to alert Emacs to which shell is being programmed. So, how can I get the shell-script-mode in Emacs to intepret #PBS -S /bin/bash to be a bash shell code?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `.emacs`:

```
(setq auto-mode-interpreter-regexp 
    "#\\(?:!\\|PBS -S \\)[ \t]?\\([^ \t\n]*/bin/env[ \t]\\)?\\([^ \t\n]+\\)")
```

That makes Emacs consider `#PBS -S` as an alternative to the `#!` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like the following to the end of the file:

```
# Local Variables:
# mode: shell-script
# End:
```

Of course, there are other ways, such as a distinct naming pattern used for setting the variable auto-mode-alist.